# i tried to add project in hardhat by npx hardhat and it comes out with the error

Tags: npm, error-handling

I was trying to create a project with the npx hardhat and npm error comes out stating could not determine executable to run...
what do you suggest to do-like how can i run npx hardhat command and create my project successfully

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have a typo. Try:

```
npx hardhat --version
```